# How do you fine tune a stargate?

Tags: stargate

In the Stargate universe DHD and the computer system used by SG command can 'fine tune' the gate address and make sure despite the gates relative positions changing (due to, as [Jeff](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/13745/3804) points out Stellar drift), that they can lock on.

Here is an image of the dialing system/co-ordinates

[image: alt]

To my knowledge, the far blue points are *fixed* by the chevrons. If the chevrons are wrong there should be nothing you can do. Also I was under the impression *only* the the chevrons in on the gate determined the location the gate went to. So how do you fine tune a stargate, when you only have chevrons to adjust, if they can be adjusted?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They don't fine-tune, they compensate for stellar drift.  This is a feature of the DHD that was not duplicated by the SGC's dialing computer.

In later seasons, greater familiarity with DHDs and gates in general lead the SGC to be able to incorporate this into their computers in near-real time (unlike the days of chugging the computer had to do in early seasons).  This is the only way they could do things they do in the later seasons  - where they are handed a random set of coordinates (not from the walls at Abydos) and dial them immediately.

Comment: Actually, I think that last part was entirely because of Jack's Ancient Knowledge Dump in SG-1 2x15, [The Fifth Race](http://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/The_Fifth_Race)

Comment: But how do you get a gate to adjust to stellar drift when you only have chevrons to play with?

Comment: @Pureferret: SCIENCE!  Also, the gate only has the chevrons.  The DHD/dialing computer does the rest.  We've never seen a gate (that's been disconnected from a DHD for a significant time) that successfully dialed.

Comment: @Jeff What else is there to do? I thought the DHD/dialing computer literally *just* put the chevrons in place. One you do that, apply enough energy and woosh you have a worm hole.

Comment: @Pureferret: apparently not, based on on-screen evidence.